# How can I add the correct depth value to a nested json object when children have multiple parents

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, depth

I'm facing an issue when trying to add a depth value to each object to a nested array.

The specific issue I'm facing is that when an object has multiple siblings the depth is applied to the first but not the others, but I need each object to have a depth value.

```js
var data = [
  { "title": "meta", "parentids": [] },
  { "title": "instagram", "parentids": ["meta"] },
  { "title": "facebook", "parentids": ["meta"] },
  { "title": "whatsapp", "parentids": ["meta"] },
  { "title": "zuckerberg", "parentids": ["instagram", "facebook"] },
]

// Assign a 'children' property to each object.
data.forEach(o => o.children = [])

// For each object assign a key/object pair
let map = data.reduce((a, o) => (a[o.title] = o, a), {})

// For each 'parentids' in each object in data push this object
data.forEach(o => o.parentids.forEach(pid => map[pid] && map[pid].children.push(o)))

let copyOfData = [...data];

let assignDepth = (arr, depth = 0, index = 0) => {
   if(index < arr.length){
      arr[index].depth = depth;
      if(arr[index].children.length){
         return assignDepth(arr[index].children, depth+1, 0);
      };
      return assignDepth(arr, depth, index+1);
   };
   return;
};

if (copyOfData.length) {
    assignDepth(copyOfData)
    console.log(copyOfData)
}
```

Comment: Can you share your exact expected output for this specific input case? Thanks. Hint: your `assignDepth` function would be a lot easier to write if you use a loop over the array.

Comment: Actually, `{ title: "meta", parentids: ["zuckerberg"] }` and `{ title: "zuckerberg", parentids: [] }` makes more sense 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of thumb with recursion: use it for depth (traversing deeper into trees), not breadth (iterating arrays). Use loops when iterating arrays, even if they're a "level" of a tree.

In this case, your recursive function is overloaded to count along arrays as well as explore deeply. But using a loop for iterating `children` arrays saves a lot of work--you can drop the index parameter from the recursive call signature. Just use recursion where it's best: exploring deeper into the tree.

```js
const data = [
  {title: "meta", parentids: []},
  {title: "instagram", parentids: ["meta"]},
  {title: "facebook", parentids: ["meta"]},
  {title: "whatsapp", parentids: ["meta"]},
  {title: "zuckerberg", parentids: ["instagram", "facebook"]},
];

const titleLookup = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map(e => {
    e.children = [];
    return [e.title, e];
  })
);

for (const o of data) {
  for (const pid of o.parentids) {
    titleLookup[pid].children.push(o);
  }
}

const assignDepth = (arr, depth = 0) => {
  for (const e of arr) {
    e.depth ??= depth;
    assignDepth(e.children, depth + 1);
  }
};

assignDepth(data);
console.log(data);
```

You could also assign node depth by traversing up the tree from each node to the root. If you hit a node that already has a depth, stop and use that as the baseline.

Additional tips:

- Use `const` rather than `let` and `var`. Only use `let` on rare occasions when you really need to reassign something, like a loop counter.
- `let copyOfData = [...data];` is a bit misleading, because it's barely a copy--the only thing that's copied here is the outermost array. All of the objects inside of it are the same. Maybe call this `shallowCopy` or something. If you really want to copy the whole original structure, you'll need recursion, or a function that recurses internally, like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`.

Comment: I get what you're saying but your rule of thumb sounds overgeneralized as worded. I don't how it so tightly associates depth with trees and breadth with arrays and makes it sound like recursion is not appropriate for arrays generally speaking, when really I think you're discouraging recursion for _iteration_ of an array.  As worded, it _sounds_ like you would discourage recursion for an operation that acts on an array at all - but a quicksort is a classic recursive algorithm that typically operates on an array, for example.

Comment: @Wyck That's right, recursion isn't appropriate for iterating arrays, at least in any language that isn't tail recursive. The reason is that (balanced) tree depth is usually logarithmic and array iteration is linear. Most languages like JS can only fit a couple thousand recursive calls deep, meaning you can easily blow the stack on trivial algorithms. Sure, quicksort is fine on arrays because it's logarithmic, D&C, and there's no obvious way to write it iteratively, but that's not what OP's doing. They're stepping by 1 along an array, basically a no-no in any imperative language.

Comment: @Wyck What you're really traversing recursively in quicksort isn't an array, it's a tree of index offsets that happen to point to subsets of the array. Quicksort uses loops to do the actual pivot comparisons and merges on the subarrays, not recursion, so if OP was writing quicksort without loops I'd have the exact same answer. But even if this weren't true, I think my answer is clear: "rule of thumb" doesn't mean "every single case". It's a general guideline that allows for some exceptions that rarely come up outside of competitive programming/school/interview puzzles.

Comment: It still comes across as "use it for trees, not arrays" which is bad (overgeneralized) advice.  If you deleted the characters `(arrays)` from your answer where you wrote `not breadth (arrays).` I'd be happier with your answer.  The text in the body of your answer isn't as clear as what you stated in your comments (I agree with your comments), so I stand by my comment.

Comment: @Wyck Thanks for the feedback, but I think a clear rule of thumb is that you use loops for arrays and you use recursion for trees. Searching "rule of thumb" on DDG gives me "A useful principle having wide application but not intended to be strictly accurate or reliable in every situation." which seems appropriate, if actually too mild. You haven't yet presented a convincing counterexample where you actually use recursion to iterate an array (quicksort is another excellent demonstration of the rule of thumb), so I'm tempted to strengthen my assertion based on this conversation.

Comment: Upvoting the answer and the constructive, polite discussion. I think I prefer your traversing up the tree idea.

Comment: Your addition of the word _iterating_ is the technical clarification I was looking for.  I appreciate the edit.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

This is @ggorlen's idea to trace lineage spelled out. I think this is simpler to read, and it doesn't create an intermediate structure (at the expense of speed for a very large data set).

```js
const data = [
  {title: "meta", parentids: []},
  {title: "instagram", parentids: ["meta"]},
  {title: "facebook", parentids: ["meta"]},
  {title: "whatsapp", parentids: ["meta"]},
  {title: "zuckerberg", parentids: ["instagram", "facebook"]},
];

// Count the (max) steps from a node with given title to a root node.
// A root node has no (valid) parentids.
const depthOf = title => {
  const node = data.find(node => node.title === title);
  if (!node || !node.parentids.length) return 0;
  return 1 + Math.max(...node.parentids.map(depthOf));
}

// Annotate each data object with its depth.
const withDepth = data.map(obj => {
  return { ...obj, depth: depthOf(obj.title) }
})

console.log(withDepth)
```

Probably fine for tree depths in the low hundreds and data arrays in the high hundreds or low thousands. You'd need to test at that scale to confirm.